# How to get mPDF 7 progress information?

Tags: php, mpdf

Sometimes the pdf export can take quite long and it would be helpful to have some indication of the remaining time, so I can give some feedback to the user.
mPDF used to have an HTML progress bar output, but this was [removed with mPDF 7.0](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/startprogressbaroutput.html).

Is there a way that I can provide a callback function to mPDF which is called every X pages created or every Y Bytes of Input-Html processed?

Is there another way to get some progress information about the status of the pdf generation?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality in mPDF.

You can get some information about the process by [utilizing a PSR-3 logger](https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/logging.html), but not remaining times, sizes, pages.

Not even the removed progressbar functionality was able to indicate remaining time - the progressbar was being updated to fixed percentual value on fixed events during the course of the PDF generation process such as parsing the document, writing fonts to the document etc.